# How to create containers programmatically in Cosmos

Tags: node.js, nestjs, azure-cosmosdb

I have the following code

```
this.client = new CosmosClient({
  endpoint: 'endpoint url',
  key: '<secret>',
})

this.container = this.client.database('database name').container('container name')
```

Which works fine.

However, now I need to programmatically or on-demand, **create new** **containers** using the JavaScript SDK, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can create containers using the [JS SDK](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/azure/cosmos-readme?view=azure-node-latest) for Azure CosmosDB NOSQL API,

Sample code,

```
await database.containers.createIfNotExists({ id: containerId });
```

Also we have a [sample](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-js/blob/main/sdk/cosmosdb/cosmos/samples/v3/typescript/src/ContainerManagement.ts#LL27C68-L27C68) in the SDK repository.